# PID Position control with ardrone

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use PID for position control of ardrone. I use ardrone_autonomy as a package to connect with Ardrone and send /cmd_vel. The values of /cmd_vel are calculated by PID controlling. The feedback Ardrone current positions are gotten from Motion Capture System. I am struggling at tuning PID parameters. Does anyone try it before?

My PID tunning, Ardrone can fly to /goal frame but still too osscilation and overshoot. My PID x,y is Kp_0.15, Ki_0.0, Kd_0.05. My target is that the position errors is about <20 cm. Is my target realistic with Ardrone? Any suggestion?

Thank you very much! I very appreciate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211391/pid-position-control-with-ardrone/) by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I usually start with just Kp and get the best performance I can with that. Then add Kd to minimize oscillations. Finally, add just a bit of Ki to ensure zero steady-state error.

Or read the wiki page and follow their recommendations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Manual_tuning

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0